# Block AWS EC2 Requests/API Calls if the CPU Utilisation is above 90%

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm currently running Amazon Linux AMI 2 OS of AWS and every now and then my Instance stops due to overload. This is happening due to multiple requests. I restart my instance everytime it stops and then it becomes normal again. I have setup a CloudWatch Notification for everytime the CPU utilization is above 90%. Is there a way I can programmatically block API calls from the server or limit number of calls per second and block all calls if the CPU utilization is above 90%?

Comment: Sounds more like you should find the underlying problem that is freezing-up the instance, rather than trying to block requests. You might be able to implement such blocking within the web server (assuming that you are running a web server, since you haven't told us anything about what's on the instance).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.